# Unable to focus input field in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, autofocus

In my snippet i have tried to set focus for first input text field. But when the page loaded it gets focused and lose the focus suddenly & closes the keyboard.
Can anyone please tell me to achieve this.

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" type="text" #username="ngModel" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autofocus clearInput required></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

add view Reference with (#) for that In your html,

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" type="text" #username="ngModel" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autofocus clearInput required  #focusInput></ion-input>
```

In your component.ts Import ViewChild and set focus of this(#focusInput) Input

Like

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('focusInput') myInput;

ionViewDidEnter() {
       this.myInput.setFocus();
    }
```

This gonna help.

Comment: Thanks Aneri. It is not working me. It showing same as previous. It open the keyboard and hides suddenly & also lose the focus.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input #exampleInput />
```

```typescript
@ViewChild('exampleInput') exampleInput: ElementRef;

setTimeout(() => {
    this.exampleInput.nativeElement.focus();
}, 300);
```

This works for me.

Note: You may want to use this timeout in `ngAfterViewInit` method or other places, and `300` milliseconds delay sounds enough in my tested devices.

Comment: Thanks Sid. It is not working me. Shows the same screen.

Comment: Sorry Sid . I have tried with only 300 millisecond. For 300 it is not working. Above 300 hundred it is working but sometimes not working. I have tried with 400 & 500, It take some delay to get focus. Is there any way to achieve this without delay.

Comment: I also experienced different result in `emulator` | `real device` | `--aot` flag was in use, so for me `--aot` flag + `real device` combination was working fine. And I haven't test it in old-phones which I am suspicious may not work well in compare with  new-phones(=better CPU). And no I don't know any other way without using timeout, please let me know if you find one! :^)

Comment: Anyway Thanks for your solution. I have one more doubt. Can you please check this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460216/gray-screen-before-splash-screen-in-ionic2-app