# Gray screen before splash screen in ionic2 App

Tags: android, ionic2, splash-screen

In my ionic app I have a splash screen. When I open the app in mobile it shows a gray screen for 2 seconds before showing the splash screen. I have tried setting theme in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Can you please tell me to achieve this ionic2 app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up

Comment: I have tried with above solution but it throws exception when taking build